# Editing sharepoint online list in Excel

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, excel, edit

For some reasons I want to edit my SharePoint online list in Excel 2013 spreadsheet. What are the possibilities?

Comment: SharePoint List Synchronizer  tool from SoftFluent is working for me to restore automatically the two-way synchronization feature between Excel and SharePoint lists.   "http://www.softfluent.com/wsslists.htm".                      But some free solution will be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not aware of an out of box solution to do this, but have you considered Microsoft Access as a solution to this?

Comment: [SharePoint List Synchronizer](http://www.softfluent.com/wsslists.htm%22)  is working good for me. Very reliable and easy to use!